# Does using a VPN avoid cellular data usage/charges?

Tags: network, privacy, vpn

As the question says, while using a VPN on my phone, will my provider still charge me for the data I'm using while connected, and can they see the data going through?

Comment: No it doesn't allow to avoid. How is this question related to information security?

Comment: @techraf thanks. i didn't really know a better board to ask it on.

Comment: The data goes through the VPN, but how do you think the VPN software on your phone sends it to the other end of the VPN?

Comment: F.Hauri - this question **is** badly located. It is off topic here - completely.

Comment: @RoryAlsop *Roaming bybassing* could be just a *border effect* of some enterprise securisation via private VPN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the provider cannot see the data in clear text if encryption is used.

Yes, the provider still charges you for the data. Although he cannot see the data in clear text he sees the encrypted data.